uint64 attribute buffers in webgl on generic gpu
I saw that https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_gpu_shader_int64.txt exists to allow you to have uint64 uniforms but there is a note

Dependencies on NV_vertex_attrib_integer_64bit
This extension only provides the ability to specify 64-bit integer input
variables in a GLSL vertex shader, but does not provide a way to specify
the values of the corresponding vertex attributes via the OpenGL API.
The NV_vertex_attrib_integer_64bit extension exactly provides that
functionality.


Which I think means I need to use nvidia hardware for the attrib buffers? If so, is WebGPU better about this, I thought it was possible to emulate uint64 even on e.g. intel integrated gpus.
